# Ethernet driver Intel 82579LM e1000e update

Tags: drivers

- I have a problem with my ethernet wired connection that doesn't work on ubuntu 13.10, using Intel 82579LM controller. On the same pc, windows 7 works perfectly, so I guess that it's a driver issue.
- The "lshw" command says that installed driver is 2.3.2-k version, quite an old one.
- I downloaded the last intel driver version e1000e-2.5.4.tar.gz, but... How to install the e1000e-2.5.4.tar.gz driver? I mean, now it's in my "home/Downloaded" folder. 2.1 - How to convert the e1000e-2.5.4.tar.gz in a "driver" format. I think I should compile it or something like that.
- Where to put the resulting driver file in order that the "modprobe e1000e" command can find it?

Thanks a lot. Of course, I'm a newbie, and as you can see my question is quite a general one: "How to update an old driver?"

Comment: ..can you ping your router?

Comment: Ping works 1/100 times. I get one answer, then long silence, then another answer. Same hardware perfectly works under windows7.

Comment: You shouldn't be using Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander. If you upgrade to 14.04 Trusty Tahr, you won't have to upgrade again until 2019.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is run the following commands in the terminal (ctrl+alt+t):

1. Run `tar -xzf e1000e-2.5.4.tar.gz`
2. Browse the path `cd archive-name`
3. This will configure the software to ensure your system has the
   necessary functionality and libraries to successfully compile the
   package `./configure`
4. This will compile all the source files into executable binaries
   `make`
5. This will install the binaries and any supporting files into the
   appropriate locations. `sudo make install`

I hope this fixes your issue, good luck.

Comment: tar -xzf e1000e-2.5.4.tar.gz >>> worked (no error message)
cd archive-name  >>>> I typed cd e1000e-2.5.4
./configure >>> told me "command not found"
make >>>> told me "no makefile found"....

indeed the makefile is inside the "src" folder....

Comment: try doing this:

1 - `cd /PATH/TO/THE/FOLDER/WHERETHEFILEIS`
2 - Run `tar -xzf e1000e-2.5.4.tar.gz`
3 - Then `cd NAMEOFTHEFILE`
4 - `./configure`
5 - `make`
6 - `make install`

Comment: as you can read in my previous comment, I already tried to follow the usual procedure that you wrote. But the step 4 (./configure), 5 (make) and 6 (make install) don't work. Step 4 message is "bash: ./configure: File or folder not found". Step 5 message is: "No target specified and no makefile found". Thanks anyway.....

Comment: If you look carefully in the previous comment i added 1 step at the start to take the terminal actions to the folder where the file is located, this should fix the problem.

Comment: thanks for your kindness. I did everything, here you find a hardcopy: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6828160/ Consider that I'm working on an italian ubuntu version, so "Scaricati" = "Download". I added a couple of "ls" commands just to show the directory content.

Comment: Addendum: <br/>

Comment: I found a **readme** file and:<br/>
I switched to the **src** folder<br/>
There the **# make install** command worked properly and ended without failure messages even if I can't guess what the result is.<br/>
The readme  says that I should find an updated **e1000e** binary file in a folder like **/lib/modules/<KERNEL VERSION>/kernel/drivers/net/e1000e/**. Indeed inside the **/lib/modules/3.11.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e** folder I found the e1000e.ko file. But if I rename it, just for a test, the make procedure doesn't rebuild it.

Answer (score 1):

December 2015, I'm setting up an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit machine, had trouble connecting to the internet when plugged into my hub, connection worked when plugged directly into ADSL modem/router.  Thought it might be a driver issue.  In e1000e version 3.2.4 from the Intel website, Makefile is in the src subdirectory.  So, once you are in the directory you unpacked,

cd src

./configure didn't work, there may be nothing to configure here.  Proceed to...

sudo make

sudo make install

...had processing messages that looked like it worked.  Unfortunately,

sudo lshw

still showed the old version of the driver.  I think this removes the old version and adopts the new one, two commands on one line:

sudo modprobe -r e1000e && sudo modprobe e1000e

The Ethernet dropped its connection and reconnected OK.  lshw now shows the updated version.  Machine is talking through router fine.  When I went to test the connection through the hub, I discovered I had originally plugged into its UpLink port.  (Doh!)  Plugged into a normal port, all is well.  No point in downgrading now...