# How to update a device driver?

Tags: drivers

How to move from a `driverfile.tar.gz` file to an installed or updated driver?

More specific: I'm a new 13.10 user. My wired network doesn't work. I found that the LAN driver could be obsolete.

I got from the INTEL website, the latest driver version in the tar.gz format. Now I don't know how to install it. Is there any standard procedure? I didn't find it on the on line documentation.

Comment: How about telling us about your ethernet device? From the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0200  What is the name of the file you downloaded?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: Further reading: [How do I install extra drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers)

Comment: And some advice: if it aint broken do not try to fix it. Any reason to WHY you want to do this? If it is to fix a problem you have: fine. If it is just because... then Ubuntu is not the operating system you should use. Ubuntu tends to use stable software. Not bleeding edge.

Comment: Thanks all for answering.
- Device INTEL 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
- Present driver e1000e ver 2.3.2-k
- Available driver e1000e ver 2.5.4 downloaded and not yet installed
- Reason of updating: the wired connection doesn't work correctly: only one PING every 60's or so, difficult (almost impossible) internet or LAN connection. The same hardware works perfectly under windows 7.

Comment: The driver e1000e v.2.3.2 works quite well in most other settings including three of my machines. I suspect it is something other than the driver. Are there any clues in: cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e eth -e e100 ? If the file is extensive, post the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6827064/

Comment: @chili555 Any idea about it? I'm stuck with no ethernet wire connection. I posted the syslog dump in http://paste.ubuntu.com/6827064/. Thanks for helping.

Comment: It looks to me like you connected: " Registering new address record for 192.168.0.110 on eth0.IPv4." and then disconnected: "<info> (eth0): device state change: activated -> disconnected (reason 'user-requested')"  What is this?? vmnetBridge: Stopped bridge eth0 to virtual network 0.  Is this a virtual machine?

Comment: @chili555 Yes I use a VmWare windows XP virtual machine. The same structure (Ubuntu 13.10 + VmWare + Virtual machine winXP works perfectly on anoter laptop, an old DELL one. The problem arises only on this "new" HP. As I explained in a parallel thread (http://askubuntu.com/questions/411545/ethernet-driver-intel-82579lm-e1000e-update) I found the updated driver on the INTEL website but I can't succeed installing it.

Comment: @chili555 Here you can find the transcription of my last attempt to compile and install updated driver: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6828160/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be sure the prerequisites are installed:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

Then compile:

```
cd ~/Scaricati/e1000e-2.5.4/src
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r e1000e && sudo modprobe e1000e
```

Verify that you are now using the updated driver:

```
modinfo e1000e | grep version
```

It ought to report 2.5.4-NAPI. Can you connect now?

You will have built the driver for your currently running kernel only. When Update Manager offers a newer kernel version, also knownn as linux-image, and asks you to reboot, you must re-compile:

```
cd ~/Scaricati/e1000e-2.5.4/src
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r e1000e && sudo modprobe e1000e
```

Comment: [SOLVED] I'm writing this comment using the wired newtork that now is working properly. Thank you so much! I should learn more about make, make install and modprobe commands. 
Here [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6848159/) the complete transcription of the installation process. I hope that it could be helpful for someone else. One should just remember that "Scaricati" is the italian name of the "Download" folder.